# How to get access to controller function from directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

So, this is my controller with some tiny function:

```
class DashboardCtrl {
  constructor ($scope, $stateParams) {
    "ngInject";

    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.title = 'Dashboard';
  }
  loadCharts () {
    // some logic here
  }
 }

export default DashboardCtrl;
```

And now my directive:

```
class TreeNodeTooltip {
  constructor ($scope, $state) {
    "ngInject";

    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.$state = $state;
    this.scope = {
        loadCharts: '&'
    };
  }
  link (scope, elem, attrs) {
    $(elem).on('click', '.node-name', (e) => {
       console.log(this.$scope.loadCharts());
       console.log(this.scope.loadCharts());
       console.log(this.$scope.main.loadCharts());
    }
  }
}
```

This is not working, i've tried couple of ways but ... How to get access to controller from directive, to controller function? Thx for help.

Comment: `<div name-of-your-directive load-charts="dashboardCtrl.loadCharts()">`. Please include the html of your directive usage

Comment: I don't need in in view ...

Comment: I have never seen directive defined in this way for Angular 1.x. The constructor injection can not work, or can it?

Comment: @Lukas if you don't need it in view, you don't need a directive..

Comment: It works fine, this is ES6 construction, that's it.

Comment: Directive doing also other things so i need it.

Comment: @Lukas I meant that the directive component is instantiated during Angular initialization. There should be no $scope available.. Scope is available only to `[post|pre]link` function.

Comment: @PavelHoral $scope is available

Comment: @Lukas Have you tried $scope.$parent?

Comment: @Lukas you **cannot** use a directive without including it in html

Comment: @devqon That is what I don't understand on the question as well. Because the "instance of the directive" class above is actually IMO instance of "directive definition"... and if OP wants to communicate with directive definition, I would say that calls for a shared service.

Comment: What is _this.$scope_ and _this.scope_ in click handler? Maybe you must simply use _scope_ from closure (without _this._)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not fully understanding what Angular's `.directive()` is doing. It is not registering class for directive instances, but it is registering [*directive factory class*](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider).

I guess that `TreeNodeTooltip` from your question is what you register as the directive factory. In that case *$injector* can inject services in the constructor, but not any actual *$scope* (not sure how it is possible you are not getting error from that).

The actual directive *instance* is being initialized through the *postLink* / *link* function. There you also have directive's scope available. However you are accessing scope from the directive definition `this.scope` and that does not make sense.

The following modification provides a bit sense to the provided code:

```
class TreeNodeTooltip {
  constructor () {
    this.scope = {
        loadCharts: '&'
    };
  }
  link (scope, elem, attrs) {
    $(elem).on('click', '.node-name', (e) => {
       console.log(scope.loadCharts());
    }
  }
}
```

And then in the template:

```
<!-- ngController only required if it is not registered as state controller -->
<div ng-controller="DashboardCtrl as dashboardCtrl">
    <tree-node-tooltip load-charts="dashboardCtrl.loadCharts()" />
</div>
```